# Hybris @XmlAttribute in bean xml definition

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is it possible to add attribute on xml element on wsDTO bean.
When controller response is xml format element can have attribute.

I tried sth like that and it didnt work.

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.search.facetdata.ProductCategorySearchPageWsDTO"
          extends="de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.search.facetdata.ProductSearchPageWsDTO">

        <description>Representation od a Product Category Search Page</description>
        <hints>
            <hint name="wsRelated"/>
            <hint name="alias">ProductCategorySearchPage</hint>
        </hints>

        <import type="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"/>
        <import type="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute"/>

        <annotations>@XmlRootElement</annotations>
       
        <property name="att" type="java.lang.String">
            <annotations scope="all">@XmlAttribute</annotations>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Edit: I got att with annotation xmlAtrribute ProductCategorySearchPageWsDTO in java code.

Edit: when calling rest controller i get att as xml element of root element and not xml attribute of root element.

Comment: I just copy your code, and I got att with XmlAttribute annotation: @XmlAttribute@ApiModelProperty(name="att")  
private String att;

Comment: Me too. But when i call rest controller i get xml with att as xml element and not att as xml attribute in root xml element.

Comment: Any idea why there is no xml attribute in response?

Comment: @Mitja What is your API response format? JSON or XML?

Comment: @geffchang Depending on "Accept" request HTTP header. So XML or JSON. I don't see anywhere that WsDTOGenericMetadatasourceAdapter has createxmlattribute function, if this is even relevant, idk. https://help.sap.com/doc/61058561bffb416395816991f147f6f0/2005/en-US/de/hybris/platform/webservicescommons/jaxb/metadata/impl/WsDTOGenericMetadataSourceAdapter.html#createXmlBindings()